# Append a querystring dynamically using sitecore SXA link component

Tags: sxa

I want to append a querystring which will have the value of current page's GUID when somebody clicks on a link. URL should look like:

```
https://some redirected url ?sc_itemid=139C9F7D-55A7-4065-9D7A-1958B3E41111
```

.
Please let me know the best way to achieve this. Is this possible without coding?

Comment: Without code, your only option is to make the content editor add this to the `query string` field on the Link properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing the [Rendering Variant](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/rendering-variants.html) for the Link rendering. Create your custom one and use Variant Template item there. Something like this:

[image]

Which will generate following HTML:

[image]

Comment: The id coming here is not of the current page. How do I get the ID of the current page?

Comment: It is not the ID of the current page but the ID of Link rendering data source. Do you need this for navigation? If yes use Navigation rendering which will generate links to the actual pages (not data source items). But if you still want to go with Link and have a link to the page you have two options: implement Variant Token or add new variable which can be used in Variant Template (both approchases requires custom implementation).